# Advantage of an alternative formula for complex gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, meromorphic-functions

We know that for $Re(z) > 0$ we have per definition$$\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}t^{z-1}dt$$ and this is well defined for the domain. If we extend the function into a unique meromorph function on $\mathbb{C}$, are we still allowed to use the definition above? I read somewhere that the problem with the formula is that the integrand is not absolute integrable near $0$. What does this mean?

Another alternative formula would be

$$\Gamma(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{1}{z+n}+\int^{\infty}_{1}e^{-t}t^{z-1} dt$$.

How is this formula not problematic compared to the previous one when we consider the domain to be the entire $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: near $0$ the power decides integrability ($e^{-t}$ is just about $1$ so has no effect) so you need $\Re z >0$ so the power is $O(t^a), a >-1$, while at infinity $e^{-t}$ dominates any power of $t$, so you have (absolute and uniform in compacts of $z$) integrability regardless of $z$; the second formulation being an integral from $1$ to $\infty$, the integral itself is entire as there is no issue at $0$ anymore

Comment: @Conrad But for $z=0$ we can just assume the integral to be infinity right? Just as we would with the infinite sum from the alternative formula above.

Comment: what about for $z=i$ where the function is holomorphic and the original integral is divergent? also the second formulation gives not only holomorphicity in the full plane except at nonpositive integers, but the behavior (simple poles, residue etc) there

Comment: @Conrad Are we allowed to just assume it to be $\infty$ whenever the integral is divergent? Since we're actually doing the same for the infinite series?

Comment: that's the whole point as the series is finite at $z=i$ (or at any nonpositive $z$ not integral) but the original integral is divergent there (and at any $\Re z \le 0$); after all $\Gamma(i)$ or $\Gamma (-1/2)$ for that matter are not infinite while the original integral would be, so that's why the regularization by residues is used (the second formula) as that gives finite values at any $z \ne -n, n \ge 0$

Comment: @Conrad thanks, I understand now. But for any $z \in -\mathbb{N}$ do we just assume that the series is infinite? Is this well defined?

Comment: yes the series is obviously infinite due to the factor $1/(z+n)$; the representation gives that $\Gamma$ has a simple pole with residue $(-1)^n/n!$ since all the other series terms and the integral are analytic at $z=-n$

Comment: @Conrad This might be a little out of context, but I'm still a little confused with meromorphic functions, for example, do we just define $1/z$ to be $\infty$ at $z=0$? So there is never negative infinity?

Comment: Mathematical notation requires a "dt" if you are integrating with respect to t.

Comment: @DanAsimov thanks, fixed

Comment: Generally speaking complex numbers have only one infinity defined by $z\to \infty$ iff $|z| \to \infty$ in the real sense iff $1/z\to 0$

Comment: @Conrad I see, I wasn't used to the definition yet but thanks for the reminder :)